# Criptografar com MD5 o nome da imagem vinda do PLUPLOAD

Tags: php

Tenho o código que uso para upload usando o PLUPLOAD.
Mas eu não queria que viesse o nome da foto original, queria que viesse CRIPTOGRAFADO, usando o md5. Estou recuperando os dados e vem o nome original da foto feito upload, queria criptografado.

Código do Upload.php

```
<?php
/**
 * upload.php
 *
 * Copyright 2009, Moxiecode Systems AB
 * Released under GPL License.
 *
 * License: http://www.plupload.com/license
 * Contributing: http://www.plupload.com/contributing
 */

// HTTP headers for no cache etc
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

// Settings
//$targetDir = ini_get("upload_tmp_dir") . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "plupload";
$targetDir = '../uploads2/';

//$cleanupTargetDir = false; // Remove old files
//$maxFileAge = 60 * 60; // Temp file age in seconds

// 5 minutes execution time
@set_time_limit(5 * 60);

// Uncomment this one to fake upload time
// usleep(5000);

// Get parameters
$chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? $_REQUEST["chunk"] : 0;
$chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? $_REQUEST["chunks"] : 0;
$fileName = isset($_REQUEST["name"]) ? $_REQUEST["name"] : '';

// Clean the fileName for security reasons
$fileName = preg_replace('/[^\w\._]+/', '', $fileName);


// Make sure the fileName is unique but only if chunking is disabled
if ($chunks < 2 && file_exists($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName)) {

    $ext = strrpos($fileName, '.');
    $fileName_a = substr($fileName, 0, $ext);
    $fileName_b = substr($fileName, $ext);

    $count = 1;
    while (file_exists($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName_a . '_' . $count . $fileName_b))
        $count++;

    $fileName = $fileName_a . '_' . $count . $fileName_b;
}

// Create target dir
if (!file_exists($targetDir))
    @mkdir($targetDir);

// Look for the content type header
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"]))
    $contentType = $_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"];

if (isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]))
    $contentType = $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"];

// Handle non multipart uploads older WebKit versions didn't support multipart in HTML5
if (strpos($contentType, "multipart") !== false) {
    if (isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
        // Open temp file
        $out = fopen($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName, $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
        if ($out) {
            // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
            $in = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "rb");

            if ($in) {
                while ($buff = fread($in, 4096))
                    fwrite($out, $buff);
            } else
                die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
            fclose($in);
            fclose($out);
            @unlink($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
        } else
            die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
    } else
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 103, "message": "Failed to move uploaded file."}, "id" : "id"}');
} else {
    // Open temp file
    $out = fopen($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName, $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
    if ($out) {
        // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
        $in = fopen("php://input", "rb");

        if ($in) {
            while ($buff = fread($in, 4096))
                fwrite($out, $buff);
        } else
            die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');

        fclose($in);
        fclose($out);
    } else
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
}

// Return JSON-RPC response
die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : null, "id" : "id"}');

?>
```

Comment: MD5 não é um algoritmo de criptografia e sim de geração de Hashes

Comment: Gostaria apenas de trocar o nome, não gostaria que fosse postado o nome original.. normalmente uso o md5 apenas para randomizar... e trocar o nome... Conseguiu compreender @ricardo Obrigado!

Comment: @AndréBaill md5 não é randômico.

Comment: Você quer gerar nomes randômicos? Mas ainda sim quer poder recuperar o nome vindo do `$_REQUEST["name"]`??

Comment: Tipo, estes nomes eu recupero eles e gravo no banco de dados... mas eu não queria gravar o nome original, queria gravar apenas um nome "ficticio" que seria o nome novo da imagem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Entendendo o que você quer**

Se eu entendi sua lógica você gostaria apenas que o nome da imagem no servidor pseudo aleatório a ponto que não interfira no armazenamento e muito menos que um terceiro adivinhe o nome da imagem e veja o que não deveria ser visto.

**Pontos Básicos**

Entenda que **criptografar** o arquivo da imagem é uma coisa e se for o que você realmente quer edite sua pergunta informando.

Entenda também que MD5 como a família SHA é apenas para geração de HASH, não é criptografia em sí.

**Solução**

O que devemos fazer é basicamente o seguinte: Na hora de salvar vamos gerar um nome aleatório usando com base o `time()` do momento e usando a função `md5` para deixar o nome "confuso" e "inadivinhável"

O que seria algo assim:

```
md5(time()));
```

e alterando seu código, creio que precisa alterar essa linha:

```
    $fileName = $fileName_a . '_' . $count . $fileName_b;
```

por esta

```
    $fileName = md5(time());
```

Não tenho capacidade de testar, por nao ter o HTML deste, mas qualquer coisa estamos aí..

Comment: Ok, funciona.. fiz isto e coloquei a extensão pelo Request, porém, na hora de inserir no banco de dados, ele insere somente o nome antigo, e o nome novo ele não insere... como eu passo esse parametro para poder inserir o nome correto?

Comment: Eu não vi em seu código a função que insere no banco de dados, precisaria vela para saber qual variável ela está a inserir

Comment: Sim para inserir no banco de dados ele retorna os registros em json, que eu recupero através do array post... mas no array post ele vem apenas os dados "antigos" e não os novos nomes...

Comment: Podes me dar um exemplo do output? Por que não vejo código JSON além de mensagens de erro em seu código original..

Comment: Ele muda sim o nome da imagem, só que no post que vem dentro de um array, fica o nome antigo.. mas vou ver se consigo remontar o script com base nisso, pra que ele faça a inserção automática quando fizer o upload da foto, já insere no banco de dados... pois ai já vai com o nome correto.

Comment: Tudo bem, se tiveres mais duvidas me chame!

Comment: Ok, onde consigo te chamar? Tem algum contato? Grato! De repente se tiver interesse, podemos desenvolver algum trabalho juntos, tenho bastante. Obg

Comment: Deixe um contato seu que retorno, Att

Comment: Skype srandrebaill